# AJAX: download new content every X seconds using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timer

I have page with posts. Initially posts was added by server-side code.
I need every 60 seconds download and show new posts from server.

Server can return 0 to N posts. Page returned by server have this format for two posts (most recent on top):

```
<div class='post' data-id='456'>...</div>
<div class='post' data-id='123'>...</div>
```

There is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var lastPostID;
    $(document).ready(function(){
            var j = jQuery.noConflict();
            j(document).ready(function() {              
              setInterval(function(i) {
                lastPostID = j(".post div:last").data("id");
                console.log(lastPostID, "lastPostID");
                j.ajax({
                  url: "/post/"+lastPostID,
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(html){
                    j("#temp").html(html);
                    j('#temp').prependTo("#posts");
                    j("#temp").empty();
                  }
                })
              }, 10000)
                });
    });    
    </script>
  </head>
    <body>
        <div id="temp" style="display: none;"></div> 
        <div id="posts">
            <div class='post' data-id='100'>...</div>
            <div class='post' data-id='20'>...</div>
            <div class='post' data-id='1'>...</div>         
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can you please recommend me any good jQuery timer plugin?

I see at JS console every 10s:

```
null "lastPostID"
```

Where I have an error?

---

Update:

If I use:

```
<script>
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('post');
console.log(divs.length, "divs with class *post*");
for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) { 
    var id = divs[i].getAttribute('data-id');
    console.log(id, "lastPostID");
}
</script>
```

Output is OK:

```
3 "divs with class *post*" jQuery_div_update.html:37
100 lastPostID jQuery_div_update.html:40
20 lastPostID jQuery_div_update.html:40
1 lastPostID
```

But with jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var lastPostID = $(".post div:last").data("id");
  console.log(lastPostID, "lastPostID");
});     
</script>
```

Output is bad:

```
null "lastPostID"
```

Why?

Comment: `any good jQuery timer plugin?` You mean, `window.setTimeout()`??

Comment: I replace ``j('temp").everyTime(10000,function(i){`` with ``window.setTimeout`` but now code run only once...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to poll some external resource (with an AJAX call, for example) you can follow the "Recursive setTimeout pattern" (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval).  Example:

```
(function loop(){
  setTimeout(function(){

    // logic here

    // recurse
    loop();

  }, 1000);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

use setInterval() instead of setTimeout()

something like:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.html",
      context: document.body
    }).done(function() {
      //do something
    });
},1000*60);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thank you. setInterval works. But JS still write every 10s to console ``null "lastPostID"``. Where I have an error?

Comment: maybe j(".post div").last().data("id"); also <div id"posts"> should probably be <div id="posts">

Comment: I fix it, but output is still ``null "lastPostID"``

Comment: this might be an issue with jquery being incapable of selecting injected html. try using jQuery's " on('ready' " instead of .ready. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You may not run into issues for this particular case (because of the large interval), but in general recursion should be used with `setTimeout` (see my answer).